# Remember me with redux storage

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have `userDetails` in `redux store` and I used `redux persist` with `redux storage` to save the details after loads page or after closing my app.

The problem is, when I logged in and I don't `checked` the `rememberMe` in index.js is checked if `!rememberMe` and do `logOut()` right after `login`.

So I need to check just at the entrance into the app for the first time and if `!rememberMe` I will call `logOut()` but if `userDetails !== 'emepty'` && `rememberMe` I will do `login()` for get valid `token`.

Why I need to check this it in the first time? because I need to reset the `uesrDetails` to guest details if `!rememberMe`.

This is my index.js:

```
const setBeforeLists = useCallback(
    (lists) => {
        beforeListsChanged(lists);
    },
    [beforeListsChanged]
);

const setUserDetails = useCallback(
    (userDetails) => {
        userDetailsChanged(userDetails);
    },
    [userDetailsChanged]
);

useEffect(() => {
//userDetails.id === 'empty' is guest.
   if (
        userDetails.id !== 'empty' &&
        !userDetails.rememberMe
        ) {
            logOut(setUserDetails, setBeforeLists);
        }
    }, [
        setBeforeLists,
        setUserDetails,
        userDetails
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh the app, the store will be reset. The token is gone. As we expected.

So, we can’t use the state to store the authentication token. This is where AsyncStorage comes onto the stage.

I'm replying to a react-native application.
If it's a web application use [session storage.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Let’s import AsyncStorage in the React Native project:

```js
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
```

Then, let’s create two functions,setToken and getToken, for storing and retrieving the persistent data. These are the main methods of this tutorial. Here, we are storing and retrieving the user data from/to AsyncStorage.

```js
async storeToken(user) {
    try {
       await AsyncStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(user));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }
  }
  async getToken(user) {
    try {
      let userDetails = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userDetails");
      let data = JSON.parse(userDetails);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong", error);
    }
  }
```

```js
componentDidMount() {
   this.getToken();
}
```

Let’s prove it. The token is thereafter you quit & reopen the app. Try it out yourself. Now, our app automatically logs you in after each session.

Hope this helps!

Comment: They say that it is not very healthy to write asynchronous operations in `componentDidMount`. Is there a more correct way we can write according to the new react life cycle order or do you not see a problem in this way? This method works by the way, thanks.